# class file optimization with the scala compiler

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I have some class file inside a jar. Now I am searching for a way to optimize that class file using some components(most notably the Inliners) of the scala compiler.
My idea is to :

1. use the ICodeReader  to emit ICode from class file
2. use an instance of the Inliner class in order to achieve the desired optimization

I am not know if that´s the right way to go

The problem is that

1. How to use the ICodeReader in order to read a class file and produce the needed ICode. ICodeReader inherits from ClassfileParser. The sole method that is for me  more probable to use is  parse(file: AbstractFile, root: Symbol) but the problem the root argument.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The Scala compiler acts on the source code and on the results of the intermediate step to produce bytecode, and will try to apply, if enabled, several optimisation.

In your case, if I understood right, you do not have the sources but the compiled classes, and I would not expect you being able to use a feature of Scala compiler on compiled classes.

What you should be looking to, in my understanding, is a bytecode optimizer , such as ProGuard, which is able to take existing bytecode and optimize it without having access to the source code

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#FAQ.html